# Bootstrap 4 grid system - using columns is there any way to wrap text around an image?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, bootstrap-4, word-wrap

I've been searching for an answer all day and have not quite found one.
Using Bootstrap 4, how does one wrap text around an image using d-flex or flex-wrap in with the grid layout with columns and rows.  I have provided my code and two image examples.  I hope this is possible.
I have viewed this example - https://www.codeply.com/api/run but it's quite different whereas the image is fixed sizing but we need the image to be responsive.
Cheers and thanks in advance.

[Example image here with photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzEoH.jpg)

[Example diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA3nY.jpg)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">


  <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
      <div class="imagebox">
        <figure>
          <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://www.bbh.co.nz/hostelImages/hi_2243_gal.jpg" alt="" />
          <figcaption class="imagebox-desc">VERANDAHS<br>
            <span class="small">Superior Central Location...</span></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><small>BPP Rating - 88%</small></div>
        <!-- this below line will wrap on all screens -->
        <div class="col-6"><small>Online Rating - 88% </small></div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right"><small>Total Beds - 50</small></div>
      </div>
      <hr style="margin: 0.5rem 0;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-6"><small>Share Rooms from NZD $30</small></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-6 text-right"><small>Private Rooms from NZD $60</small></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at assum perpetua dissentiet sit, et sea probatus sententiae ullamcorper, voluptatibus signiferumque ex has. No vel postea scripta alienum, eam te enim feugiat ornatus. Exerci quidam melius has ad. Mel ut ludus choro
          instructior. Erat dictas antiopam quo ea, pri at audiam offendit.Cetero albucius pri ne, erant nobis aliquip cu sit, eam dolore.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: set image width to 100%

Comment: To clarify further, in Bootstrap I need to find a class that allows the listing div class behave as a "row" up to 995px then change to "column".

Comment: Thanks @Anjali but that doesn't work either.  I've tried that in the past.  It's got something to do with the way I think I have laid out the rows and columns.  The last row needs to somehow become a flex-row for med screens to allow to wrap but not sure how this really works.

Comment: you can reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663441/is-there-really-no-way-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-in-flexbox) to rewrite

Comment: @Felicia you can set the row width manually and set its background

Comment: @ChunbinLi thanks for that reference which I had already checked out previously but it doesn't work with the rows and columns of the ratings and total rooms that sit at the top right of the image - as per my diagram.  These areas are an issue when it comes to wrapping the text around the image where the text is situated in the same column as the image in a <p> tag.  They need to  move to be under the image directly on a small screen.  And the reference example does not allow for that.

Comment: @Anjali would you mind giving me an example of what you are referring to please?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this, by giving `background-image` on the row and its property to set it one center of the div
here is an example - https://jsfiddle.net/erymag7b/27/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and for trying but it's not presenting what we require.  The Img must stay to the left of all content up until small screen size where it sits above all content.  The ratings and total room info must stay right of the image. I think my issue has something to do with combining Flex and Grid and nesting correctly but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float:left` in *.imagebox* to wrap text around an image and use `clean:both` in *P tag* to let text under an image

https://codepen.io/lichunbin814/pen/yqEOKm?editors=1100

> tip : [Avoid Inline Styles for CSS Design](https://www.lifewire.com/avoid-inline-styles-for-css-3466846)

```css
.imagebox {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

div.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

figcaption.imagebox-desc {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.7rem 0 0.5rem 1.2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.imagebox-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .text {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="imagebox">
        <figure class="imagebox-inner">
          <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://www.bbh.co.nz/hostelImages/hi_2243_gal.jpg" alt="" />
          <figcaption class="imagebox-desc">VERANDAHS<br>
            <span class="small">Superior Central Location...</span></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div><small>BPP Rating - 88%</small></div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"> <small>Online Rating - 88%   </small> <small>Total Beds - 50</small></div>
      <hr class="m3">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><small>Share Rooms from NZD</small><small>Private Rooms from NZD</small></div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><small>$30</small><small>$60</small></div>
      <p class="mt-2 text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque explicabo aspernatur delectus voluptate, nesciunt quibusdam ab reprehenderit, non et temporibus. Aut commodi, voluptates nulla deleniti pariatur vitae vel eos sit asperiores aliquid,Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, at assum perpetua dissentiet sit, et sea probatus sententiae ullamcorper, voluptatibus signiferumque ex has. No vetua dissentiet sit, et sea probatus sententiae ullamcorper, voluptatibus signiferumque ex has. No vetua dissentiet
        sit, et sea probatus sententiae ullamcorper, voluptatibus signiferumque ex has. No v molestiae recusandae placeat corporis earum assumenda dolorem! Earum necessitatibus tempora enim nisi officiis in. Ducimus illo placeat eveniet.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```