# Floating image and text wrap for order list

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cross-browser

It there any way to make the bullet looks normal in IE11 with floating image and text-wrap?

**Below is the screen for chrome (Ideal):**
[image: Screen for chrome]

**Below is the screen for IE11:**
[image]

```
<style>
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
ol {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
    left: 15px;
}
</style>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
<div>Below are bullets</div>
<ol>
    <li>This is the bullet</li>
    <li>This is the bullet</li>
    <li>This is the bullet</li>
    <li>This is the bullet</li>
    <li>This is the bullet</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there really no way to wrap text around an image in flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663441/is-there-really-no-way-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-in-flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to modify the code and try to achieve the result as close as other browsers.

I applied the media queries and I try to set the list-style-position, text-indent, and padding specifically for the IE browser.

Now it looks almost similar as it looks in other browsers.

Modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Untitled Page</title>
      <style>
         @supports not (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
         {
         img 
         {
         float: left;
         margin-right: 10px;
         }
         ol 
         {
         position: relative;
         padding-left: 5px;
         left: 10px;
         }
         #container
         {
         width:300px;
         background-color:skyblue;
         padding:5px;
         }
         }
         @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) 
         {
         img 
         {
         float: left;
         margin-right: 35px;
         }
         ol 
         {
         position: relative;
         padding-left: 5px;
         margin-left: 10px;
         }
         ol li 
         {
         list-style-position: inside;
         text-indent: -1.8em;
         padding-left: 1em;
         }
         #container
         {
         width:300px;
         background-color:skyblue;
         padding:5px;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
         <div>Below are bullets</div>
         <ol>
            <li>This is the bullet This is the bullet This is the bullet</li>
            <li>This is the bullet</li>
            <li>This is the bullet</li>
            <li>This is the bullet This is the bullet This is the bullet</li>
            <li>This is the bullet</li>
            <li>This is the bullet</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output in the IE 11 and Google Chrome browser:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your own requirement.

Comment: Thanks deepak. It looks great! But list-style-position will mess up the text wrapping start on second line. I want to keep the list item showing properly when they are in multiple lines. Are there any ways to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows the issue with the multiple lines? I will try to check it and try to find any possible solution for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Sure, I want to show the list item properly like this. https://imgur.com/d12k92C

Comment: Please check the updated answer. It may help you to fix your issue. You can modify it as per your own requirements.

Comment: That great Deepak-MSFT, this is what I want. I just modified some padding on css and it works fine. @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  ol {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: 1.8em;
    left: 1.8em;
  }
  ol li {
    list-style-position: inside;
    text-indent: -1.8em;
    padding-left: 2em;
  }