# Dynamic flexbox/float, auto-sizing images and boxes, need paragraphs to wrap within and margins to work

Tags: html, css

This (dynamic flexbox with auto sizing images and wrapping paragraphs, etc.) works fine except that the paragraph wrapping around the image and associated margins/padding won't work right for me. The paragraph elements wraps as desired, but extend beyond the parent and I cannot seem to get the margins to look good. Can you?

Code adapted from various sources, some of those links included below.

Borders are just so you can see what I think is the problem.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: 2px solid purple;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  <!-- margin-right: 1em;
  -->
}

p {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  outline: 2px solid orange;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}


/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
  <h1>Responsive Image Gallery</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
  <p>website source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_responsive.asp
    <br />image gallery code location (below): https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery
  </p>
  <p>responsive website code lcoation (commented out below): https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_website2
  </p>
  <p>This stackoverflow (SO) question shows how to wrap text around image within the flexbox like I do in the code below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663441/is-there-really-no-way-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-in-flexbox
  </p>
</div>
<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">

    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" />
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:50%" />
      <p>test text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text here test text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text here</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" /></div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" />
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:50%;" />
      <p>test text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text here test text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text heretest text here</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" /></div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" /></div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png" style="width:100%" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me please? Still waiting. Thanks!